# Upon wake, PCIe USB card with USB WiFi dongle plugged in fails because network starts before USB interface

Tags: linux, networking, wifi-configuration

I have an older motherboard with a PCIe USB 3.0 card. Into that is plugged a WiFi adapter that provides network connectivity. Everything works fine until the machine is put into sleep/suspend. Upon wake, the network fails to come up because I think the machine tries to bring up the network before the USB card comes back up. Afterwards I can just restart the network, which works as the USB interface is up by then, but it would be nice to have the OS wait for the USB interface to come up first before trying to turn on networking. Is there anything I can do to prioritize bringing up USB or otherwise make this work as intended?

Edit: The WiFi driver is the MediaTek driver, as the WiFi adapter uses the well-supported MT7612U chip. I don't have this problem when using the built-in USB 2.0 ports on the motherboard. Also, the USB 3.0 chip on the card is the Renesas/NEC one, but I can't recall the actual model at the moment. The point is this is all very well-supported hardware on Linux so I'm not sure why this is happening.

Comment: Network drivers often fail after suspend on Windows (also Ethernet devices). Check the used driver and the web page of the manufacturer of the Wifi chip if there is a newer driver available.

Comment: @Robert I believe it's a kernel driver. It's a Mediatek chip, which is supported by the 5.15 kernel I'm running. I don't think it's the driver, however as the problem doesn't occur if I use one of the motherboard's USB 2.0 ports.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood right, the command
`sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service`
fixes the problem.

The solution would then be to add it as a wake script.

From
[Running scripts before and after suspend with systemd](https://blog.christophersmart.com/2016/05/11/running-scripts-before-and-after-suspend-with-systemd/):

> Simply put an executable script of any name under
> /usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/ that checks whether the first argument
> is pre (for before the system suspends) or post (after the system
> wakes from suspend).
>
> If it is `pre`, then do the thing you want to before suspend, if it’s
> `post` then do the thing you want to do after resume. Simple!
>
> Here’s a useless example:
>
> ```
> #!/bin/sh
> if [ "${1}" == "pre" ]; then
>   # Do the thing you want before suspend here, e.g.:
>   echo "we are suspending at $(date)..." > /tmp/systemd_suspend_test
> elif [ "${1}" == "post" ]; then
>   # Do the thing you want after resume here, e.g.:
>   echo "...and we are back from $(date)" >> /tmp/systemd_suspend_test
> fi
> ```

Comment: Correct, I just use systemctl to restart the network. Great idea, I'll give this a try and see if it works.